# Finding the largest even number in list

Tags: prolog

The point of this program is supposed to be to find the largest even number inside a list. For example, the query:

```
? - evenmax([1, 3, 9, 16, 25, -5, 18], X]
X = 18.
```

The way I thought to do this is to separate the list into two, one with just odd numbers and one with just even numbers. However, after doing that, I legitimately have no idea how to take the even-number list specifically and find the maximum integer in that.

Here is what I currently have:

```
seperate_list([], [], []).
separate_list([X|Xs], [X|Even], Odd) :-
    0 is X mod 2,
    separate_list(Xs, Even, Odd).
separate_list([X|Xs], Even, [X|Odd]) :-
    1 is X mod 2,
    separate_list(Xs, Even, Odd).

find_max([X|Xs], A, Max).
    X  >  A,
    find_max(Xs,X,Max).
find_max([X|Xs],A,Max) :-
    X  =<  A,
    find_max(Xs,A,Max).
find_max([],A,A).
```

I am still a newcomer to Prolog, so please bear with me...and I appreciate the help.

Comment: Your actual question can be answered simply with "sort, reverse, take the first element, as in `sort(Even, Sorted), reverse(Sorted, [Max_even|_])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but... if you need the maximum (even) value... why don't you simply scan the list, memorizing the maximum (even) value?

The real problem that I see is: wich value return when there aren't even values.

In the following example I've used `-1000` as minumum value (in case of no even values)

```
evenmax([], -1000).  % or a adeguate minimum value

evenmax([H | T], EM) :-
  K is H mod 2,
  K == 0,
  evenmax(T, EM0),
  EM is max(H, EM0).

evenmax([H | T], EM) :-
  K is H mod 2,
  K == 1,
  evenmax(T, EM).
```

**-- EDIT --**

Boris is right: the preceding is a bad solution.

Following his suggestions (thanks!) I've completely rewritten my solution. A little longer but (IMHO) a much better

```
evenmaxH([], 1, EM, EM).

evenmaxH([H | T], 0, _, EM) :-
  0 =:= H mod 2,
  evenmaxH(T, 1, H, EM).

evenmaxH([H | T], 1, M0, EM) :-
  0 =:= H mod 2,
  M1 is max(M0, H),
  evenmaxH(T, 1, M1, EM).

evenmaxH([H | T], Found, M, EM) :-
  1 =:= H mod 2,
  evenmaxH(T, Found, M, EM).

evenmax(L, EM) :-
  evenmaxH(L, 0, 0, EM).
```

Comment: This has worked for me. Thank you. The reason why I did not try to do both at the same time is simply because I thought seperating the lists would be easier, rather then working on both requirements at the same time.

Comment: The solution to your problem, "wich value return when there aren't even values" is quite easy: don't "return", just fail. I leave you alone now, and [here is a funny picture](https://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: @Boris - I knew that picture but is ever funny; and you're right: I was wrong: the solution is don't return if there isn't a even number; and thank for the `=:=` tip (I have a lot of problem with Prolog operators); modified my answer, hoping this is better.

Comment: @Anstane - thank for the accepting my solution but is very bad; modified my answer following suggestions from Boris (you should accept is answer).

Comment: @max66 I don't care which answer is accepted, as long as the accepted answer is not misleading (esp. to a beginner). Your answer after the edit is already much better.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in one go. You can find the first even number in the list, then use this as seed and find the largest even number in the rest of the list.

But if you don't insist on doing it in a single traversal through the list, you can first collect all even numbers, then sort descending and take the first element of the sorted list.

```
evenmax(List, M) :-
        include(even, List, Even),
        sort(Even, Sorted),
        reverse(Sorted, [M|_]).

even(E) :-
        E rem 2 =:= 0.
```

If you want to see how `include/2` is implemented, you can [look here](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/apply.pl?show=src#include/3). Basically, this is a generalized and optimized version of the `separate_list/3` that you have already defined in your question. `sort/2` is a built-in, and `reverse/2` is a library predicate, [implementation is here](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#reverse/2).

There are many other ways to achieve the same, but for starters this should be good enough. You should ask more specific questions if you want more specific answers, for example:

- What if the list has free variables?
- What if you want to sort in decreasing order instead of sorting and then reversing?
- How to do it in a single go?

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I define `evenmax` like there is no member of list L which is even and is greater than X:

```
memb([X|_], X).
memb([_|T], X) :- memb(T,X).
even(X) :- R is X mod 2, R == 0. 
evenmax(L, X) :- memb(L, X), even(X), not((memb(L, Y), even(Y), Y > X)), !.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already a number of good answers, but none that actually answers this part of your question:

> I legitimately have no idea how to take the even-number list
>   specifically and find the maximum integer in that

Given your predicate definitions, it would be simply this:

```
evenmax(List, EvenMax) :-
    separate_list(List, Evens, _Odds),
    find_max(Evens, EvenMax).
```

For this `find_max/2` you also need to add a tiny definition:

```
find_max([X|Xs], Max) :-
    find_max(Xs, X, Max).
```

Finally, you have some typos in your code above: seperate vs. separate, and a `.` instead of `:-` in a clause head.